# Is there a sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $\lim_n t_n = \infty$, $\lim_n \Delta_n = 0$ and $\sup_n S_n < \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of non-negative real numbers such that $t_0 =0$. We define induced sequences $(S_n)_{n\ge 1}$ and $(\Delta_n)_{n\ge 1}$  by
$$
\begin{align}
S_n &:= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_i}, \\
\Delta_n &:= \sup_{i \in \{ 0, \ldots,n-1\}} \frac{t_{i+1}-t_i}{t_n}.
\end{align}
$$

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716728/is-there-a-sequence-t-n-n-ge-0-such-that-sup-n-s-n-infty) thread, I got that there is a sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $\lim_n t_n = \infty$ and $\sup_n S_n < \infty$. Now I would like to ask if there is a sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that $\lim_n t_n = \infty$, $\lim_n \Delta_n = 0$ and $\sup_n S_n < \infty$.

Thank you so much for your elaboration!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is indeed **no**.

Fix $m\in \mathbb N$

\begin{align}
S_n &= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{1 - \frac{t_k}{t_n}}\left(\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_n} - \frac{t_{k}}{t_n}\right)\\
&\ge \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1-\left(\frac{t_k}{t_n}\right)^m}{1 - \frac{t_k}{t_n}}\left(\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_n} - \frac{t_{k}}{t_n}\right)
\end{align}

This proves that $$\sup_n S_n \ge \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1-\left(\frac{t_k}{t_n}\right)^m}{1 - \frac{t_k}{t_n}}\left(\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_n} - \frac{t_{k}}{t_n}\right) = \int_{0}^1 \frac{1-u^m}{1-u}\mathrm d u = \sum_{\ell = 1}^{m} \frac1\ell \to \infty$$

---

What we proved here is:

> If $\left(t_n\right)$ is a increasing sequence of real numbers such that: $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\sup_{i\in\left\{0,\ldots,n-1\right\}} \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n} = 0$$ then $$\sup\limits_{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{t_{k+1} - t_k}{t_n - t_k} = \infty$$

Comment: Could you confirm that your proof implies $[\lim_n \Delta_n = 0 \implies \sup_n S_n = \infty]$?

Comment: I add what we proved in a statement at the end of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'm clear.

Comment: by the way you don't need the fact that $t_n \to \infty$

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is **no**, but my proof has a little gap in it which turned out to be surprisingly difficult, and right now I'm not sure how to fill it in.

---

Suppose that such sequence $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$ exists. Let $\tau(x)$ be a continuously differentiable strictly increasing function that interpolates $(t_n)_{n\ge 0}$, that is,
$$\tau(k) = t_k\; \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$$
Note that
$$\int_{i}^{i+1} \frac{\tau'(s) ds}{t_n - \tau(s)}\le
\int_{i}^{{i+1}} \frac{\tau'(s) ds}{t_n - t_{i+1}} = \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}}$$
(the inequality follows from the fact that $\tau$ is increasing)

Integrating over intervals and summing up the inequalities, we obtain a bound
$$
\int_{0}^{{n-1}} \frac{\tau'(s) ds}{t_n - \tau(s)} \le
\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}\frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}} := S'_n
$$
If we manage to prove that $S'_n$ are bounded, we will arrive at a contradiction, because we can compute the integral explicitly:
$$
\int_{0}^{{n-1}} \frac{\tau'(s) ds}{t_n - \tau(s)}
= \int_{t_0}^{t_{n-1}} \frac{d\tau}{t_n - \tau}
\\
= \log (t_n - \tau)\Big|_{t_{n-1}}^{0}
= \log \frac{t_n}{t_n - t_{n-1}} \ge \log \frac{1}{\Delta_n} \to \infty
$$
because $\Delta_n \to 0$. So it remains to show that $S'_n$, and at the moment, I am not sure how to do this.

---

**Edit**: thanks to @Youem, I realized that $S'_n$ is not necessarily bounded, because in fact any of the terms $\frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}}$ can be unbounded. However, we don't need $S'_n$ to be bounded for the argument to work, we just need $\lim\inf S'_n < \infty$, and as it turns out, it suffices to show that $\lim\inf$ of the maximum of the terms is bounded.

**Claim**
$\lim\inf \max_{i \in \{0, \ldots, n-2\}} \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}} < 2 $

Proof:

Suppose the contrary, then from some point $N$, we can then choose $i$ such that
$$ \frac{t_{i} - t_{i-1}}{t_n - t_{i}} \ge 2\; i \in \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$$
whenever $n > N$
We can then write
$$t_n \le t_{n_1} + \frac{1}{2}(t_{n_1} - t_{n_1 - 1})
\le t_{n_1} + \frac{1}{2}(t_{n_1} - t_{n_2})
\le t_{n_2} + \frac{1}{2}(t_{n_2} - t_{n_2 - 1})
+ \frac{1}{4}(t_{n_2} - t_{n_2 - 1}) \\
= t_{n_2} + (t_{n_2} - t_{n_2 - 1})\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\right)
\le \ldots \le t_m + (t_m - t_{m-1})\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots\right) \le t_{m-1}$$
where $m \le N$. Hence $\forall n > N$ we get
$t_n \le \max_{m < N} t_m$, so that $(t_n)_n$ is bounded - contradiction $\square$

Now we can prove that $\lim \inf S'_n < \infty$:

In view of the above claim, choose as large $n$ as we like, such that
$$\max_{i \in \{0, \ldots, n-2\}} \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}} < 2$$
In that case, we have
$$\frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}} - 
\frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i}}
= \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}}\frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i}}  \le 2 \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i}}$$
Therefore
$$\frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i+1}} \le 3 \frac{t_{i+1} - t_i}{t_n - t_{i}}\\
\Rightarrow S'_n \le 3 S_n$$

Comment: (+1) I hope the remaining issue will soon be fixed.

Comment: Ths proof still imcomplete. It seems that you are saying that $t_{i+1} - t_i \le t_n - t_{i+1}$ which is not forced.

Comment: @Youem, thank you, I didn't notice that flaw, will try to think how to fix it now.

Comment: @Youem, in fact, just the term $\frac{t_{n-1} - t_{n-2}}{t_n - t_{n-1}}$ can be unbound, so it seems that this approach is doomed:(

Comment: @Youem, I think I managed to fix the argument (although your solution is, of course, more elegant).